# Return multiple instances of SSRS report inside report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a multi-value parameter, for which each value I need to render a copy of a report.

I have a main report w/ a multi-value parameter.  The main report has a list control, with a subreport inside.  The main report calls a stored procedure that splits the comma delimited multi-value parameter, and returns it to the dataset.

I'm having 2 problems:
1) When it returns multiple copies of the subreport, it's always the report for the first item in the comma delimited list
2) Occasionally, when I attempt to have more than one value in the multi-value parameter, it throws an error saying "One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport, 'SubReport1', located at: ."

How can I get the subreport to show for each value in the multi-value parameter?

Comment: Don't know if you found a solution to this. If not, can you give information on the parameters that are getting passed between main report and sub report? I tested a list using dataset to pass one value to a sub report and it works fine.

Comment: On the main report, I have a multi-value parameter of type integer called RequestIDs.  I pass this value to a stored procedure that will return the comma-delimited list as a dataset.  The subreport has a parameter called RequestID.  I need to figure out how to pass each value in the dataset as the parameter value of the subreport.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Added answer. Please clarify if the requirement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of simple report and I think the logic is the same or I may have misunderstood your requirement.

Added a List object to main report. In List object add data from dataset and sub report.
In the sub report there is a parameter called @subParam1

[image]

Sub report parameter setting passing data from dataset.

[image]

Select Multiple parameters. This will be passed to the stored procedure and the dataset returns 3 records:

ABC

DEF

GHI

[image]

Preview output is

[image]

Comment: Yep, this worked.  I was attempting to pass a parameter into the subreport parameter, instead of passing a field from the dataset.  It was much easier than I was making it out to be.  Thanks for the help!